# $injector.get is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make autenticate-interseptor. The core idea is simple: when server-request fails we must login user by http-auth. Code look like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.authentication')
    .factory('AuthenticationInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$location', 'Session',

  function AuthenticationInterceptor($location, $q, $injector, Session) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        var currentUser = Session.currentUser();

        if (!currentUser || !currentUser.id) {
          if ($location.path() !== '/login') { $location.path('/login'); }
        } 

        return config;
      },
      responseError: function(response) {
        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
          var $http = $injector.get('$http');

          Session.destroy();

          $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  }

  ]);

})();
```

I need this `var $http = $injector.get('$http');` here because of circullar injection error. But when i use that module, i get the error `TypeError: $injector.get is not a function`

So, how can i inject $http here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your injections does not match the strings in the array.

```
angular
  .module('app.authentication')
  .factory('AuthenticationInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$location', 'Session',
  function AuthenticationInterceptor($location, $q, $injector, Session) {
```

You are telling angular to inject the $location service as the third argument to the `AuthenticationInterceptor` service, but you are using the third argument as if it is the $injector. Change your code to the following:

```
angular
  .module('app.authentication')
  .factory('AuthenticationInterceptor', ['$location', '$q', '$injector', 'Session',
  function AuthenticationInterceptor($location, $q, $injector, Session) {
```

Comment: np - Please upvote/accept one or both of the answers. It looks like we both answered at the same time, with basically the same answer.

Comment: Sorry, i cannot accept the answer for more 9 minutes )

Answer (score 0):

```
'$q', '$injector', '$location', 'Session'
 $location, $q, $injector, Session
```

You haven't respected the same order.

Do yourself a favor, and use ng-annotate to never have this bug again.